# Possible to retrieve all of the user's applications on the device?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to retieve a list of paid applications from the user's device? Does it contain information such as Name, Version, Price, Icon? I would think a reasonable way is to get all the installed applications, then query for any applications that are paid.

Comment: I hope not. That would be a privacy leak of immense proportions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the question [How to get the List of Installed Applications in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093463/how-to-get-the-list-of-installed-applications-in-android) is on a similar topic.

The method your are looking for is : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications(int).

You definitely can get the name, version and icon, but I don't think you can retrieve the price (which I find quite fair).